# Proper family deformation retracts onto special fiber

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, complex-geometry

If $\mathbf{D}$ is the complex unit disc with coordinate function $s$ and  $X \to \mathbf{D}$ is a proper flat holomorphic family (and it is smooth outside of the fiber $s=0$), will the total family $X$ deformation retract onto the fiber above $s=0$?

I don't believe this will be true, but I cannot find a counterexample. My idea was that if $X$ is a family of elliptic curves degenerating to a singular cubic, then this would fail (but, I think it actually works in this case!).

**Edit**: in the comments, the consensus is that this should be true - but we do not have a proof yet.

Comment: Deligne (SGA 7 II, Exp. XIII, second paragraph of the introduction) suggests that something slightly stronger might be true. I'm sure it has been worked out since, but I don't know a reference. In any case, we know that in the algebraic case the inclusion of the special fiber induces an isomorphism on cohomology and fundamental groups...

Comment: Thank you for the reference - I am interested in the proof, if anyone knows a reference.

Comment: This is true (i.e. $X$ does deformation retract onto the special fiber $s^{-1}(0)$).  I unfortunately don't know a reference (and would also be interested in seeing one).

Comment: I think this can be deduced from sections 1.5 and 1.7 of the book "Stratified Morse theory" by Mark Goresky and Robert MacPherson.

Comment: @PiotrAchinger Do you mean sections 1.5 and 1.7 from Part 1? If so, can you elaborate? I don't see how to get the deformation retraction from the cited sections.

Comment: If X is smooth, choose a metric and then flow by $\nabla |s|^2$

Comment: @VivekShende Perhaps I don't understand - isn't the point that the central fiber will have singularities? I'm not sure how such a flow would work in that case.

Comment: @improv305: even though the special fibre may have singularities, the total space can still be smooth. This is already an interesting case that is often studied in algebraic geometry. For example, I believe that in your elliptic curve example, the total space should be smooth (but you should check this).

Comment: If $X$ is smooth, use the flow mentioned by @VivekShende. In general, by resolution of singularities, one can find $\pi: X' \to X$, a proper birational morphism which is an isomorphism outside the special fibre. One can then define a retraction for $X$ by simply composing the flow on $X'$ with $\pi$. This clearly gives a well defined set-theoretic map and continuity follows from the properness of $\pi$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is the reference:

Persson, Ulf, 
On degenerations of algebraic surfaces,
Mem. Amer. Math. Soc. 11 (1977), no. 189.

Clemens, C. H. Degeneration of Kähler manifolds. Duke Math. J. 44 (1977), no. 2, 215-290.

I found the reference here
http://web.math.ucsb.edu/~drm/papers/clemens-schmid.pdf
also worth reading

Morrison, David R.
The Clemens-Schmid exact sequence and applications,
Topics in transcendental algebraic geometry (Princeton, N.J., 1981/1982), 101-119,
Ann. of Math. Stud., 106, Princeton Univ. Press, Princeton, NJ, 1984.